# jQuery - filter by visibility, and if checked

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have some code that shows/hides checkboxes using the visibility attribute. If the button is visble, when the form is submitted, I need to somehow ensure that *all* visible checkboxes are indeed checked.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($(':checkbox:visible:not(:checked)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('visibility') != 'hidden';
    }).length) {
        alert('return false');
    }
});
```

The problem seems to be that $(this) after the filter is the form rather than the checkbox.

Any suggestions would be very welcome, than you!

Comment: In your code, `this` refers to the form, that is why it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WUGh3/1/

```
if ($('.checkbox:visible:not(:checked)').length) {
    alert('not all visible checkboxes are checked');
    return false;
}
```

​So you just check if there is any visible checkbox that is not checked. And if so - return `false`

PS: as adviced by @bažmegakapa the more efficient way of writing the same is:

```
if ($('.checkbox:not(:checked)').filter(':visible').length) {
    alert('not all visible checkboxes are checked');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, although unfortunately with this even if I check all visible checkboxes, it still returns false

Comment: @Nick: it works for me - please take my jsfiddle and modify the html part so js fails: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WUGh3/2/ http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WUGh3/3/

Comment: Might be worth moving `:visible` out of the query selector.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: It wouldn't change behaviour anyway, but indeed may be useful for performance

Comment: @zerkms Might be wrong, but then the native DOM querySelectorAll() could be used instead of firing jQuery's engine. See my answer for details.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder if it's because I used the visibility attribute? http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WUGh3/2/ (unfortunately I cannot use regular show/hide as it messes with the jQuery UI CSS)

Comment: @Nick: I'm not sure I understand you :-(

Comment: @zerkms Is there any way to update the filter with .css("visibility") == 'visible' ?

Comment: @zerkms - many thanks, is there a way to get $(this) to be the checkbox rather than the form though?

Comment: @Nick: uhm, in my latest example it is a checkbox. You probably need to share some code

Comment: @zerkms Sorry I didn't explain myself very well - I only want to run the check when they submit a form, I have updated my initial post

Comment: @Nick: so just take my code as is and replace `alert` with `return false`. Hm?

Comment: @zerkms - sorry, not sure if I'm doing something wrong (as per my initial post now) but it returns false even with everything visible checked

Comment: That is awesome, thank you so much! Really appreciate your help, and for guiding me through all of this :)

Answer (score 2):

In your solution, `this` refers to the form itself, and `is()` only runs on one element, the first one in the jQuery collection, so you should take a different approach.

In this compact one, you simply filter the visible ones, then filter the ones that are not checked, and if there is any, you return false (what you return in the end is the result of the `==` operator).

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    return $('.checkbox').filter(':visible').not(':checked').length == 0;
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSzvL/)

**Note:** compared to the solution of @zerkms, I basically break the selector up. `:visible` is not a selector that can use the native browser selector engine if it is available (see [Additional Notes in the manual](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)).

Comment: Many thanks, I think I may need to change my code because :visible doesn't seem to work with css({"visibility":"hidden"});

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('.checkbox').filter(':visible')
```

Checks to see if there are any visible checkboxes with the class `checkbox`.

You then check the **form** object to see if it's checked, which it isn't because forms cannot be checked.

You probably want to do something like:

```
var checkBoxes = $('.checkbox').filter(':visible');
var returnValue = true;

// Check if each visible checkbox is checked
checkBoxes.each(function(){
    if(! $(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      returnValue = false;
    }
});

return returnValue;
```

[Here's a working demo for you](http://jsfiddle.net/jFKf9/)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can see, $(this) refers to the form, rather than to a checkbox.